# Parallel merge sort (using fork)

Tags: c, fork, mergesort

the function sorts the elements of an array v which are located in the interval [s,e] (v[s],v[s+1],..,v[e] will be sorted).
For the array `3 2` it gives `2 3`
But for an array with more than 2 elements like `3 2 4` it gives back the array unchanged.

```
void merge(int v[],int s, int e)
{
    if(e==s)    return; //if there is just one number
    int m=(s+e)/2;
    pid_t f1,f2;
    if((f1=fork())==0){merge(v,s,m);exit(0);} //sort the numbers from position s to position m
    if((f2=fork())==0){merge(v,m+1,e);exit(0);} //same for numbers from position m+1 to e
    waitpid(f1,NULL,0); //wait until the first half is sorted
    waitpid(f2,NULL,0); //same for the second half
    int *t=(int*)malloc((e-s+1)*sizeof(int)); //temporary array for merging the 2 halves
    int k=0,i=s,j=m+1;
    while((i<=m)&&(j<=e)) //while there are stil unprocessed numbers left in each half
        if(v[i]<v[j])   t[k++]=v[i++];
        else            t[k++]=v[j++];
    while(i<=m)         t[k++]=v[i++]; //copy the remaining numbers
    while(j<=e)         t[k++]=v[j++];
    while(k)            v[e--]=t[--k]; //copy them back in the original array
    free(t); //delete the temporary array
}
```

Comment: Test input/output? Better indentation? Algorithm description? Debugging? These are all properties of a good question yours does not fulfill in the slightest way.

Comment: I am of the impression that while your fork'd processes can read the same data as their parent, when they write to that data some behind-the-scenes magic makes them a private copy (where all future read/write operate from) such that they cannot modify the parent's memory... which would preclude what you're doing until you refactor to threads instead. Now, considering your parallel work only needs to run when you have more than 2 numbers, which fits your failure case...

Answer (score 1):

After you fork your two processes are not sharing the same data, they start out with identical copies but they make their own changes, the parent process doesnt see their changes

If you want to parallize you must either

- put the array in shared memory
- use threads (they share common memory)
- use an IPC mechanism to stream the sorted data back for the merge

Answer (score 0):

If you're not attached to merge sort specifically, here's a [forking quick sort](https://gist.github.com/BenGoldberg1/b9b510be84dedf13bfe3), which always pivots on the first element.  Also, it uses popen/pclose instead of explicit fork/waitpid.